# Return custom object in jpa that have list

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have two entity like this

```
@Entity
Class Project {
    long id;
    String name;

    @OneToMany
    List<Prop> props;
}

@Entity
Class Prop {
    long id;
    double price;
    String createdUser;
}
```

now i write a query

```
select new com.example.ProjectReport(
        p.id, p.name, pr.price
    ) from Project p left join p.props pr
```

```
Class ProjectReport {
    long id;
    String name;
    double price;
}
```

the resutl of query return for each prop relations with project 
but i need something like this and this not working :

```
Class ProjectReport {
    long id;
    String name;
    List<Double> priceList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select new Map(p.id, p.name, pr.price, pr.price) from Project p left join p.props pr")
```

Comment: Thanks, but if we dont know how many price is available in prop , how to handle this?
and is there any way to cast map to my CustomClass ?